# internal protected virtual with Guid

Tags: asp.net, iis

Very weird issue, to me at least.  This is an ASP.NET MVC web application and the function call is coming in via a Web API method.  I'm running using IIS version 6 on Windows 8.1 rather than IIS Express.

I've got a function in a different project within the same solution with this signature:

```
    internal protected virtual bool IsUsernameAvailable(string username, int userID, Guid institutionID)
```

When I call it, the function is not run.  The debugger either simply skips it 
or IIS throws an exception, "An unhandled win32 exception occurred in w3wp.exe [4892]"

I've got plenty of other internal protected virtual methods and they all work fine.  If I make the method private or public it works as well, but then I can't stub it when unit testing.

The key thing is that, if I pass an object containing the parameters it's OK.  I think that the Guid parameter is causing the problem.

Is this an IIS bug?

Thanks